# XML etree dynamical scraping Python

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I'm trying to parse xml file using python library xml.etree.ElementTree. As the result I need to get all testcases which could be in different testsuite on behind testsuite. As the result I need to get the list of dictionaries with next fields (testcase.name, testcase ) and list with testsuite names.

Example of output now:

```
[   {   'internal_id': '2503988',
    'name': 'C++ extentsion',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']},
{   'internal_id': '1680735',
    'name': 'JAVA: DELETE with CURSOR OF. Dynamic DELETE with CURRENT OF '
            'clause',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']},
{   'internal_id': '1680736',
    'name': 'Python interpreter',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']},
{   'internal_id': '5684390',
    'name': 'Next test case is here',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']},
{   'internal_id': '880055',
    'name': 'Second test case is here',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']},
{   'internal_id': '999443',
    'name': 'test data',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests',
                          'Test folder for testsuite',
                          'name_of_testsuite']}]
```

Output, which I need to get

```
 [   {   'internal_id': '2503988',
    'name': 'C++ extentsion',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites'
                          ]},
{   'internal_id': '1680735',
    'name': 'JAVA: DELETE with CURSOR OF. Dynamic DELETE with CURRENT OF '
            'clause',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests'
                      ]},
{   'internal_id': '1680736',
    'name': 'Python interpreter',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Temporary location of old data collection tests'
                      ]},
{   'internal_id': '5684390',
    'name': 'Next test case is here',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Test folder for testsuite'
                      ]},
{   'internal_id': '880055',
    'name': 'Second test case is here',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'Active CQM regression test suites',
                          'Test folder for testsuite'
                      ]},
{   'internal_id': '999443',
    'name': 'test data',
    'testsuite_path': [   '',
                          'name_of_testsuite'
                      ]}
```

]

Here is an example of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testplan>
    <name><![CDATA[]]></name>
    
    <testproject>
        <name><![CDATA[CQM]]></name>        
        <prefix><![CDATA[CQM]]></prefix>        
        <internal_id><![CDATA[500348]]></internal_id>
    </testproject>

    <testsuite id="" name="">
        <testsuite name="Active CQM regression test suites" >
            <node_order><![CDATA[0]]></node_order>
            <details><![CDATA[]]></details>
            <testsuite name="Temporary location of old data collection tests" >
                <node_order><![CDATA[1]]></node_order>
                <details><![CDATA[]]></details>
                <testcase internalid="1680735" name="JAVA: DELETE with CURSOR OF. Dynamic DELETE with CURRENT OF clause">
                    <externalid><![CDATA[14814]]></externalid>
                </testcase>
                <testcase internalid="1680736" name="Python interpreter">
                    <externalid><![CDATA[15688]]></externalid>
                </testcase>
            </testsuite>
            <testcase internalid="2503988" name="C++ extentsion">
                    <externalid><![CDATA[95476]]></externalid>
            </testcase>
            <testsuite name="Test folder for testsuite" >
                <node_order><![CDATA[5]]></node_order>
                <details><![CDATA[]]></details>
                <testcase internalid="5684390" name="Next test case is here">
                    <externalid><![CDATA[14814]]></externalid>
                </testcase>
                <testcase internalid="880055" name="Second test case is here">
                    <externalid><![CDATA[43267]]></externalid>
                </testcase>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="name_of_testsuite">
            <testcase internalid="999443" name="test data">
                <externalid><![CDATA[63333]]></externalid>
            </testcase>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
</testplan>
```

My code right now is pretty poor, I can only get all testsuite, but no idea how to move forward:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def get_all_testsuites(testcases, result_testcase_list = [], testcase_path=[]):
   testsuites = testcases.findall('testsuite')

   if len(testsuites):
       for testsuite in testsuites:
           testcases = testsuite.findall('testcase')
           testcase_path.append(testsuite.get('name'))

           if len(testcases):
               for testcase in testcases:
                   result_testcase_list.append({'name': testcase.get('name'), 'internal_id': testcase.get('internalid'), 'testsuite_path': testcase_path})

        
           get_all_testsuites(testsuite, result_testcase_list, testcase_path)
    else:
        pass

    return result_testcase_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcases = ET.parse('testcases.xml')
    print(get_all_testsuites(testcases))
```

#### Updated

Upgraded the code, but it returns wrong path.

Also, I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code really looks perfect. The only problem is the concept of **pointers**.

When you assign the `testcase_path` variable to the final object `result_testcase_list` it does not store the current value of the variable, it stores a pointer to it (a memory address) which means, every future mutation on this variable will be reflected in the final object in every point it was assigned.

To be able to solve that you need to create a new copy of `testcase_path` in a not mutable way.

```
def get_all_testsuites(testcases, result_testcase_list = [], testcase_path=[]):
    testsuites = testcases.findall('testsuite')

    if len(testsuites):
        for testsuite in testsuites:
            testcases = testsuite.findall('testcase')
            # creating a brand new variable and NOT using a mutation method 
            #    like 'append', but operating them with '+' 
            current_path = testcase_path + [testsuite.get('name')]
 
            if len(testcases):
                for testcase in testcases:
                    # using the new variable here ...
                    result_testcase_list.append({'name': testcase.get('name'), 'internal_id': testcase.get('internalid'), 'testsuite_path': current_path})
                # ... and here
            get_all_testsuites(testsuite, result_testcase_list, current_path)
    else:
        pass

    return result_testcase_list
```

UPDATE: Corrected the indentation when calling the recursion.